# How to handle changing URLs in CSS local vs. production

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

We are using Visual Studio 2010 and in our production environment we put a bunch of our resources on a CDN.  However, when we are debugging locally, we want to pull the resources from a relative local path.

So in our CSS, I'd like to be able to have our CSS as when I run it locally:

```
.foo {
    background:url(../images/bar.jpg);
}
```

However, when I publish to Azure, I want to have the CSS automatically update the path to:

```
.foo {
    background:url(http://cdn.company.com/website/images/bar.jpg);
}
```

Is this possible in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this likely isn't the answer you're looking for, but for reference, you could do this with the `FileUpdate` Task in [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), which would look something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <TargetAddress>../images</TargetAddress>
    <TargetAddress Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">http://cdn.company.com/website/images</TargetAddress>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="DeployCSS">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ScriptFiles Include=".\css\*.css"></ScriptFiles>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ScriptFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ScriptFiles->'$(DeployPath)css\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"></Copy>
    <FileUpdate Encoding="ASCII" Files="@(ScriptFiles->'$(DeployPath)css\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" Regex="\.\./images" ReplacementText ="$(TargetAddress)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: You wrote "I realize this likely isn't the answer you're looking for". Why ? It is the only correct process and solution.

Comment: @Softion Mainly because I don't think of it as being something *in* visual studio. [Though one can change that, I now know.](http://www.richardhallgren.com/running-msbuild-scripts-from-visual-studio/)

Comment: Regex file replacement definitely the way to go.  But its worth nothing that CSS paths are relative, so its easier to just relocate the CSS file and keep the same folder structure for assets as opposed to relocating just the assets that the CSS references.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for and it was great that you linked to the external article showing how to use MSBuild from within VS.

Comment: A solution without Visual studio would be to switch hosts: use absolute ref for all assets using a dedicated domain, set this domain on developer machines to go to an internal common machine using the hosts file. Assets will not be in TFS but who cares as you should not change an asset by overwriting it (because of public caching) so you have no use of versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are sir. As do most developers, I recommend using separate stylesheets for the various applications you need to address. ;)

You can simply add a Literal to your markup in your <head> like so...

```html
<asp:Literal ID="DynamicCSS" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then use the following code to load them dynamically based on the request origin.

```vb
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Request.Url.Host = "localhost" Then
        DynamicCSS.Text = "<link type=""text/css"" rel=""Stylesheet"" href=""Styles/style1.css"" />"
    Else
        DynamicCSS.Text = "<link type=""text/css"" rel=""Stylesheet"" href=""Styles/style2.css"" />"
    End If
End Sub
```

```cs
private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    if (Request.Url.Host == "localhost") {
        DynamicCSS.Text = "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"Stylesheet\" href=\"Styles/style1.css\" />";
    } else {
        DynamicCSS.Text = "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"Stylesheet\" href=\"Styles/style2.css\" />";
    }
}
```

*Note: I didn't test the C# code, but I guess it ought to work the same.* Cheers ;)

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the stylesheet and manage changes in both. instead, I want to have a single stylesheet as described in the question with replacement vars.

Answer (score -1):

You could place the base url in the web.config file, and use web config transforms to modify it based on where it is published.

Some Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: No one said the CSS had to be static.  This is ASP.net, it could be generated server side.

Comment: An example would appear to be in order.